# How to apply automated query after each insert with condition?

Tags: mysql

If I have a table like that:

```
id | name | points 
------------------
1  | Hala | 50
2  | Asa  | 60 
3  | Hala | 1000
```

How can I apply automated query that applied after each insert but with condition

like this query but only to apply on the latest item after it is inserted

```
update points set points = points / 10 where name = 'Hala';
```

Comment: You could try it with Triggers: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a trigger like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger AFTER  INSERT ON MyTable
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.points = NEW.points/10;
END
```

Comment: How can I add condition to it?